# Why didn't this get marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I recently asked [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79355/what-are-these-red-markings-on-this-lens) on photo.se about IR focus markings.
But, later I found [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/what-do-the-red-values-mean-on-the-distance-scale-of-a-lens?rq=1), it was also about the same problem..
Why didn't my one get marked as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Finding duplicates relies on users of the site remembering older questions, or doing searches, or sometimes noticing the "Related" questions that appear in the sidebar.  Usually someone will pick up on it, it will get reviewed and voted on, and then possibly closed as a duplicate.  In the meantime your question will usually attract answers, especially when it's not obvious a duplicate may exist.

Answer (score 2):

Mike obviously has the general answer here, but in your case I'd almost be tempted to mark the older question as a duplicate of yours: in many ways, yours is a *better* question as it includes the image of the lens front and centre; that's much clearer for anyone else finding the question on the site than the slightly vague description on the earlier question.

Comment: Whoa! I didn't think that **my** question could do such a thing.....